# How to find Bottleneck from Oracle Explain Plan

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, oracle12c

Any Oracle SQL tuning Expert can help me to understand the below explain plan to spot the bottleneck . Thanks in advance.

This query is responding instantly , still i am looking for potential changes or modifications to my code after understanding the explain plan. so far its all look good for me as per my knowledge . i feel cost to high for this returning one row overall .

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                       |                             |    25 | 10000 |  6105   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                                         |                             |    25 | 10000 |  6105   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   VIEW                                                 |                             |    25 | 10000 |  6104   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    WINDOW SORT                                         |                             |    25 |  9625 |  6104   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     WINDOW SORT                                        |                             |    25 |  9625 |  6104   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      WINDOW SORT                                       |                             |    25 |  9625 |  6104   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS ANTI                                |                             |    25 |  9625 |  6101   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS OUTER                              |                             |    25 |  8800 |  6001   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |         NESTED LOOPS OUTER                             |                             |    25 |  8125 |  5950   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |          NESTED LOOPS OUTER                            |                             |    25 |  7675 |  5875   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |           NESTED LOOPS OUTER                           |                             |     7 |  1862 |  5850   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |            NESTED LOOPS OUTER                          |                             |     5 |  1200 |  5825   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |             NESTED LOOPS OUTER                         |                             |     5 |  1165 |  5821   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |              NESTED LOOPS OUTER                        |                             |     4 |   760 |  5807   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |               NESTED LOOPS OUTER                       |                             |     4 |   684 |  5797   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |                NESTED LOOPS OUTER                      |                             |     4 |   568 |  5793   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  16 |                 NESTED LOOPS OUTER                     |                             |     4 |   540 |  5793   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  17 |                  NESTED LOOPS OUTER                    |                             |     4 |   424 |  5789   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |                   NESTED LOOPS                         |                             |     4 |   396 |  5789   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  19 |                    NESTED LOOPS                        |                             |    57 |  1995 |  5630   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  20 |                     INLIST ITERATOR                    |                             |       |       |            |          |
|* 21 |                      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | NU_LOV_ENTRY_1              |     3 |    36 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |                     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| PARTY                       |    22 |   506 |  1876   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|* 23 |                      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IDX_HOME_STORE_PARTY        | 14838 |       |    41   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 24 |                    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | PERSON                      |     1 |    64 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 25 |                     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | XPKPERSON                   |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 26 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                    | XPKLOV_ENTRY                |     1 |     7 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  27 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID           | TRANSLATION                 |     1 |    29 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 28 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                    | XPKTRANSLATION              |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 29 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                      | XPKLOV_ENTRY                |     1 |     7 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  30 |                TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID             | TRANSLATION                 |     1 |    29 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 31 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                      | XPKTRANSLATION              |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 32 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED      | PARTY_LEGAL_HOLD            |     1 |    19 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 33 |                INDEX RANGE SCAN                        | XIF3PARTY_LEGAL_HOLD        |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 34 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED       | ADDRESS                     |     1 |    43 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 35 |               INDEX RANGE SCAN                         | IDX$$_036C0004              |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  36 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                | STATE_PROVINCE              |     1 |     7 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 37 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                         | XPKSTATE_PROVINCE           |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 38 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED         | PHONE                       |     1 |    26 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 39 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN                           | IDX$$_036C0003_1            |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  40 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED          | AGREEMENT_PARTY             |     4 |   164 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 41 |            INDEX RANGE SCAN                            | XIF2AGREEMENT_PARTY         |     4 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  42 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                   | AGREEMENT                   |     1 |    18 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 43 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                            | XPKAGREEMENT                |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  44 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED            | INSTALLMENT_NOTE            |     1 |    27 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 45 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN                              | IDX_INSTALLMENT_NOTE_AGR_ID |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 46 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED             | AGREEMENT_PARTY             |     1 |    33 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 47 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                               | UQ_AGREEMENT_PARTY_1        |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

Comment: Show us the query and table definitions.

Answer (score 3):

1. No explain plan is "wrong" considered in and of itself. Every plan Oracle generates is potentially the right plan. What matters is whether it's assumptions about your data are on target or not. A plan only becomes "bad" when it is generated based on bad data assumptions. Therefore nobody can look at a plan by itself and tell you what's wrong.
2. If your query is responding instantly, what needs fixing? Your plan shows some WINDOW SORTs at the end, meaning all rows have gone through the nested loops steps before it and moved through sort, so there isn't anything left to do (e.g. you have good throughput, not just good response).
3. Ignore COST. It means nothing - Oracle will always choose the plan that has the lowest cost per its calculations, but when its data assumptions are wrong, its calculations will result in *incorrect* COST figures, often (though not always) leading to bad plans. If you do have a bad plan, the COST you see is by definition wrong, so should not be given a moment's thought. Focus instead on what the plan is actually doing and where it's cardinality estimates are wrong. If your query is performing well and the COST seems to high, so what? You got lucky, and bad costing didn't mess up the plan. Go with it.
4. If you do end up dealing with a poorly performing SQL and want to know where the bottleneck is, the only way to pinpoint it with assured accuracy is to use wait-sampling data. Every Oracle database since 11g has ASH data with `sql_plan_line_id` exposed, which can be used to find which step in the plan is spending most of your query time, and focus tuning efforts at that point. Find the `sql_id` and query `v$active_session_history` and group by sql_plan_line_id, counting the rows. The row count is the number of seconds spent on that step. Your investigation can be further aided by actual-cardinality-per-step information which can be obtained from `v$sql_plan_monitor`, which will help explain the timings you see in ASH.

Comment: very well explained much appreciated  , this helps me a lot during analysis , i am using 12C version and trying to write a query from session_history as per your input to see the bottle necks if end up with poorly performing SQLs.                                             
        ```select sql_plan_line_id from v$active_session_history 
where sql_id =  <SQL_ID>
group by sql_plan_line_id;```                                                                                       
  am i doing it right please add if any to be corrected .

Comment: that's right.. add COUNT(*) to your select list.

Comment: Or get a SQL Monitor report

Comment: @user1402648 I agree with BobC - it's much easier to run `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor('your SQL_ID') from dual;` or to use OEM (if you have it) than to directly query `v$sql_plan_monitor`.